# php max() and min() on associative array

Tags: php

```
print_r($pages);
print max($pages);
print min($pages);
```

shows me

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 ) 1 2
```

While I was expecting the last two numbers to be 3 and 1. How come?

EDIT: further info

```
$pages = $v->plaintext;
var_dump($pages);
$exp = explode("|", $pages);
print_r($exp);
print max($exp);
```

gives

```
string(324) " 1 | 2 | 3 " Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 ) 1
```

Not sure what the "string(324) is? It's still outputting "1" as the max($exp) ...

EDIT: found solution, I was dealing with strings. This now works and prints out 3.

```
$pages = $v->plaintext;                 
$exp = explode("|", $pages);
$exp = array_map("trim", $exp);
$exp = array_map("intval", $exp);
print max($exp);
```

Comment: Not reproducible. http://www.ideone.com/3ml8C

Comment: Same here, works for me (http://codepad.org/1dXCg7B4) `$pages` does not even look like an associative array.

Comment: "$pages does not even look like an associative array" - how do you mean?

Comment: "associative array" is associated with something more like `array('foo'=>1, 'bar'=>3)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me.

```
$a=array(1,2,3);

print_r($a);
print max($a);
print min($a);
```

You'll need to dump more debug info for your $pages var to dig more.

Comment: Thanks, var_dump of $pages led to me to the solution.